# Rendering content based on category items in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using [this howto](http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django.html) for writing a blog app. I have created two category items: news and events. I want to rended the posts belonging to those categoris seperately. When a specific template is called, only the posts belonging to the categories specified should get displayed.

Comment: Post some code. How far have you gotten with this? What don't you understand? Where are you having problems? You can't get help if you don't ask the right questions

Comment: I have just copy pasted from the howto link posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have two views, one for rendering your news, and one for rendering your events:

```
def news_view(request):
    blog_posts = Blog.objects.filter(category__title="news")

    return render(request, "news.html", {"posts": blog_posts})


def events_view(request):
    blog_posts = Blog.objects.filter(category__title="events")

    return render(request, "events.html", {"posts": blog_posts})
```

Then you just need to create your templates and the proper url handlers in urls.py and you're good to go.